# How to call multiple Makefiles from a main Makefile all in the same directory

Tags: makefile

I have several Makefiles, one per executable, say Makefile.exec1, Makefile.exe2

Here is the structure of those:

```
SRC_CPPS = test2.cpp
EXEC     = test2

# uncomment for debug mode
_DEBUG=YES

include utils/sample.Makefile
```

sample.Makefile defines some environment variables for libraries to link with and define some rules to produce EXEC from SRC_CPPS.

I would like to write a main Makefile to run all the Makefile.something.
Here is a try, which does not work:

```
MAKEFILES= $(shell ls Makefile.* | grep -v "~")

all:
    $(foreach var,$(MAKEFILES), make -f $(var))

clean:
    $(foreach var,$(MAKEFILES), make -f $(var) clean)
```

Comment: Where are the rules that actually define targets for the binaries listed in EXEC? Are those in utils/sample.Makefile? What happens exactly when you run the makefile you list above?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
MAKEFILES=$(wildcard Makefile.*)
APPS=$(subst Makefile.,,$(MAKEFILES))

all: $(APPS)

%: Makefile.%
        $(MAKE) -f $<
```

Not entirely sure I rightly understood what you were asking, though. Seems like a bit of a convoluted setup...

Answer (score 1):

Remember to never use `make` when invoking sub-makes.  Always use `$(MAKE)`.

I recommend something like this:

```
MAKEFILES := $(filter-out %~,$(wildcard Makefile.*))

all: $(addprefix all.,$(MAKEFILES))

$(addprefix all.,$(MAKEFILES)): all.%:
        $(MAKE) -f $* all

clean: $(addprefix clean.,$(MAKEFILES))

$(addprefix clean.,$(MAKEFILES)): clean.%:
        $(MAKE) -f $* clean

.PHONY: all $(addprefix all.,$(MAKEFILES)) clean $(addprefix clean.,$(MAKEFILES))
```

However, I wouldn't do it this way.  That's a lot of extra overhead, invoking recursive makes.  If you restructure your individual `Makefile.*` a bit so they don't use the exact same variable names to hold sources, you can just use `include $(filter-out %~,$(wildcard Makefile.*))` in the top-level makefile, and build everything without recursion.